# Timidity and Pulse-Audio playback

Tags: sound, wine, pulseaudio, midi

I'm interested in getting Guitar Pro 5 up and running in Ubuntu. Tried Tuxguitar but it's far too clumsy to do any long term work so I got myself Wine and installed Guitar Pro. I can launch it and play sound through Timidity with success. However, there seems to be a serious restriction in that only one output (Pulse-audio or Midi) can be active at any given time.

My issues:

1. I can't play web browser or system audio while Guitar Pro (midi) is active.
2. I can't play GP audio after playing system audio either through a browser or through an audio player such as Audacious or VLC.
3. After playing any type of system audio, I have to select a new Timidity port in the GP settings after which system audio becomes "blocked" and only GP audio is heard. I have to completely exit GP in order to restore system sound function.

Of course, this makes it next to impossible to transcribe audio (my main hobby with this software) or simply do any type of general audio work while the software is running. Apparently it's a known issue with *Timidity in general* as noted here:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/timidity/+bug/210472

Specifically comment #19

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/timidity/+bug/210472/comments/19

To quote, the user suggests:

> **"run pulseaudio in system mode and add the timidity user to
>   pulse-access group"**

which I am not sure how to go about. This OS is still a new environment to me and I'd refrain from messing with permissions. Can anyone give me a guideline on how to achieve this, or find an alternative solution altogether?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks if you're read this far.

PS: Like stated above this problem is not related to Guitar Pro but Midi playback in general. Tuxguitar was giving me the same grief when I was using Timidity ports so I had to switch to Gervill playback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem after trying the following command in the terminal:

```
timidity -iA -B2,8 -Os &
```

*Note*: `-Os` is the captal letter o, not the numeric value of 0.

More technical info below.

What this does is launch a new instance of Timidity under ALSA.
Under `timidity --help`, `-iA` signifies "ALSA sequencer interface" and `-Os`  signifies "ALSA pcm device". In the end this results in no interference between audio playback from both Timidity and Pulse-Audio softwares. You will have to adjust your Timidity port accordingly, as by default there is usually an instance of Timidity running under Root. You will get a message saying something like

> Opening sequencer port: 130:0 130:1 130:2 130:3

This usually corresponds to the last instance of Timidity that is open. To get successful playback I chose Port 0 under the last 3 port choices available. Note that if you escape the command with Ctrl-C the process will still be active under Jobs, and be visible in the System Monitor. To properly terminate an active process first run the command `jobs` in the terminal, then run `kill%x`, where x corresponds to the job number related to the timidity command above.